# Fade Music with CCAction

Tags: c++, action, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to create a fade in/out effect on music transitions.
I've created a CCFadeMusic action that is inherited from CCActionInterval
so if I do something like this from a layer it works fine (it just updates music volume inside update (float) function):

```
CCFiniteTimeAction* fadeOut = CCEaseIn::create(CCFadeMusic::actionWithDuration(2.f, CCFadeMusic::OUT), 2.f);
CCFiniteTimeAction* fadeIn = CCEaseIn::create(CCFadeMusic::actionWithDuration(2.f, CCFadeMusic::IN), 2.f);
this->runAction(CCSequence::createWithTwoActions(fadeOut, fadeIn));
```

But this actions will be destroyed on scene transition.

I know it is possible to schedult a selector without adding class as a child like this:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getScheduler()->scheduleSelector(schedule_selector(ClassName::func), this, time, false);
```

But is there a way to run an action on a CCNode that is not added as a child to anything? (I tried running action on a singleton class and it didn't work).

Or there is some other way to fade in/out music without using CCActions?

I thought of not autoreleaseing these actions, but it seems like a bad idea, and I don't really want to pass `this` in every place I want to play a music file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, in a singleton that is inherited from CCNode you can just do this

> CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getActionManager()->addAction(CCSequence::createWithTwoActions(fadeOut,
>   fadeIn), getInstance(), false);